# Locating first in a VBO with different objects inside

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I have a single VBO which I'm storing two different objects in.
Object A consists of vertices, colors and texture coordinates.
Object B consists of vertices and colors.

Now what I'm trying to do here is to switch between the two models using a keyboard button. So far I have managed to isolate the first model however I'm having issues trying to find a good way of telling glDrawArrays where the second model begins and ends. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to *isolate/use* different models stored in a single VBO.

Using: `glDrawArrays(mode, first, count);`

I guess you've calculated `first` and `count` wrong, remember you need to multiple `first` and `count` with the amount vertices you use per face. If the mode is `GL_TRIANGLES` then the amount of vertices per face is 3.

Then you want to call it like this:

```
glDrawArrays(mode, faces_to_skip * 3, count_faces_to_use * 3);
```

Remember the `count` is the total size, and not the size/offset from `first`